# Генератор паролей на Python 3 с использованием модулей

Tags: python, строки, случайные-числа

У меня появилась небольшая проблемка:
Я сделал генератор паролей, должен быть случайный boolean (has_symbols и has_uppercase).

Если has_symbols = True, то в пароле будет один символ из данного списка: [#, @, !]
Если has_uppercase = True, то в пароле будет одна буква верхнего регистра.

Код:

```
import random, os, string # Imports

while 1: # Infinite cycle!
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits # Combining all lowercase letters and all digits
    random.seed(os.urandom(1024)) # RaNdOmNeSs!!1

    password_length = 7 # Password length, you can change it
    password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for length in range(password_length)) # Password generation

    print(password) # Printing
    input('» ') # Waiting for user to input, so the program can generate a new password
    os.system('clear') # Clearing screen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import random
import string

def generate_password(password_length, has_symbols=False, has_uppercase=False):
    symbols = "#@!"
    alphanum = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    uppercase = string.ascii_uppercase

    chars = []

    if has_symbols:
        chars.append(random.choice(symbols))

    if has_uppercase:
        chars.append(random.choice(uppercase))

    chars.extend(random.choice(alphanum)
                 for _ in range(password_length - len(chars)))

    random.shuffle(chars)
    return ''.join(chars)

while True:
    print(generate_password(7, random.randrange(2), random.randrange(2)))
    input()
```

Comment: Не пойму, куда именно вставлять этот код.

Comment: @bitt8 дополнил ответ.